# Select2 Jquery, add item and prevent custom items, only allow items in dropdown list

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using Select 2 (https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters/dropdown), but need to prevent custom inputs, I only want inputs returned by the json.  I also want to add another item ("Other") permanently as the first item in the drop down for all queries. Is this possible and how?

```
$('[id*="_form_cars"]').select2({
    placeholder         : 'Enter your car',
    minimumInputLength  : 2,
    tags                : true,
    allowClear          : true,
    dataType            : 'json',
    ajax: {
        url     : $('[id*="_formcar"]').data("url"),
        delay   : 250,
        data    : function(params) {
            return { term: params.term }
        },
        results: function(data, page) {
            results: data
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: One way to do it would be to initialize (or create only, don't initialize) the `select2` object. Then fetch the dropdown values from the ajax. In the `success` callback of the ajax, you'll have to reinitialize the select like `$("#select2-ddl").select2();`

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show a code example?  Thank you